# Keep the partition type unchange when to dd a file into it

Tags: filesystems, dd, openwrt

List the file type on sdb:

```
debian@debian:~$ sudo blkid |grep  sdb
/dev/sdb1: UUID="19a2c9fa-f793-415d-9e25-082fa3bbbb3d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="eb3ae1bb-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="11d2d221-e53e-4828-8e3e-50e63ffb01ce" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="eb3ae1bb-02"
```

DD a image file into sdb1.

```
debian@debian:~$ sudo dd if=openwrt-19.07.7-x86-64-combined-ext4.img of=/dev/sdb1   bs=4M
68+1 records in
68+1 records out
285736960 bytes (286 MB, 272 MiB) copied, 0.156294 s, 1.8 GB/s
debian@debian:~$ sync
```

Show the file type again:

```
debian@debian:~$ sudo blkid |grep sdb
/dev/sdb1: PTUUID="eb3ae1bb" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="eb3ae1bb-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="11d2d221-e53e-4828-8e3e-50e63ffb01ce" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="eb3ae1bb-02"
```

How to keep the partition type unchange when to dd a file into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but by using `dd` you are taking the image and replacing the partition content (so the existing `ext4` filesystem) with the image, which is a disk image -- it has a partition table, so you are creating a partition table on top of a partition (and this isn't supported so kernel won't try to discover partitions on `sdb1`). So you either need to use the entire `sdb` (or another, empty, disk) for the image or if you want just the "data" from the image, unpack it (create a loop device from it using `losetup -f openwrt-19.07.7-x86-64-combined-ext4.img`) and copy the data to `sdb1`.

You could copy the image after the `sdb1` superblock to keep the ext4 header intact but you'll still get corrupted ext4 after that.